# add spans and characters into paginate_links

Tags: pagination, query, localization

I am using paginate_links on my custom page query.

What I have already works sweet and this is the code I have so far...

```
<?php
    global $wp_query;

    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base'      => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
        'format'    => '?paged=%#%',
        'current'   => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total'     => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'prev_text' => __('&#8592; Previous'),
        'next_text' => __('Next &#8594;')
    ));
?>
```

Though I really need to be it a bit more different, but can't find any documentation on how to bend the rules with it.

**Question 1**
I need the *prev_text* and *next_text* to be translatable. I have been adding my *theme text domain* for localization through-out my theme. And on generic text strings, I have been using this `<?php _e('Latest Dowloads','mythemetextdomain'); ?>`. How can I add my theme text domain into the *prev_text* and *next_text* string.

**Question 2**
How can I add `<span class="bracket">[</span>` and `<span class="bracket">]</span>` between each of my paginated page numbers?

Please see image below of what my current pagination is looking like.

[image]

Now see image below of what I'm trying to achieve by using spans and brackets.

[image]

Can any help me modify my paginate query above to get these 2 things to work? Or is it not possible?

Thanks

Comment: If you really want brackets cross-browser, why not consider using a CSS background to archieve that effect, you won't need to mess with filters or code, simply apply an appropriately made image via CSS(it might seem odd, but it would be a simple solution).

Comment: There is a filter you could use for string replacement, but following on from what i said above, this would actually be really easy using CSS to apply background images to those items(and works around needing to do any filtering). If you are determined to add brackets literally though, let me know and i'll provide a real answer.. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function paginate_links() can return "plain", "list" and "array" (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links). Just define the type as array then you'll be to display it as you want:

```
<?php
    global $wp_query;

    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

    $paginate_links = paginate_links( array(
        'base'      => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
        'format'    => '?paged=%#%',
        'current'   => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total'     => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'prev_text' => __('&#8592; Previous'),
        'next_text' => __('Next &#8594;'),
        'type'      => 'array'
    ));

    foreach ( $paginate_links as $pgl ) {
        echo "[ $pgl ]";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the brackets, I'd try to do:

```
.pagenumber:before { content:'['; }
.pagenumber:after { content:']'; }
```

And you can also use margins, paddings, positioning, etc. to get it exactly how you want it.

Comment: Yeah this is what I thought about doing but content: is not IE7 compatible, suppose I could live with that. Also pagination I don't think is not outputting li's. Thanks

Comment: This is what is was talking about but use the `page_number` class instead.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: Use `__` (double underscore) instead of `_e`.

Question 2: There may be a filter or hook available to do this but you can also use CSS to generate content for the `page_number` class.

Comment: Thanks for question 1 so, I wrote it like this...

'prev_text' => __('&#8592; Previous','mythemetextdomain'),
'next_text' => __('Next &#8594;','mythemetextdomain')

Comment: Suppose I could get clever with css, but would rather out markup if you know what I mean. Thanks